# How can I follow JEST RAM usage?

Tags: node.js, performance, jestjs, ram

I'm actually working on some monkey testing of a central piece of our application.
To do so I use Jest as a test runner and fast-check (and @fest-check/jest) to generate datas and actually tests my calls.

It's not really important to this question but here is the first test I've wrote

```
describe('localResolveValue', () => {
  getFormDynamicFieldApi.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve('api-proxy'));

  test.prop([valueCache, interpolableAlias, parameters, staticValue])(
    'should return the value in the builder field if statically defined',
    async (cache, aliases, parameters, value) => {
      const resolved = await localResolveValue(cache, aliases, parameters)(value)(emptyFormBuilder, undefined);
      return resolved === value.value?.toString();
    },
  );
});
```

*interpolableAlias*, *parameters*, *staticValue* are three Arbitraries that I defined outside and are pretty large.

Using fast-check and large Arbitraries I was prepare to see some big RAM usage, but not the 16Go I'm seeing right now. It seams to be related to seed and data generation as, sometimes, it works with very little RAM usage.

This kind of RAM usage isn't acceptable for our whole test suite running in parallel, let alone for a single test. Therefore I tried to find where the RAM usage was coming from in the hope of mitigating it on my end or fix it in fast-check.

To do so I used the recommended command from Jest documentation :

```bash
node --inspect-brk --expose-gc ./node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand --logHeapUsage
```

And open the chrome://inspect and launch the corresponding debugger. But it seams to only be able to see a 25Mo usage, sometime a bit more, but nothing of the sort I'm looking for.

I checked with top and I can see a node process going all the way to the moon and, most of the time, crash. And then I get

> A jest worker process (pid=54870) was terminated by another process: signal=SIGTERM, exitCode=null. Operating system logs may contain more information on why this occurred.

Which, yes it did crash. But Why am I not seeing it in the debugger ? Also, why is Jest spawing a worker when I clearly added the *--runInBand* part ? Documentation clearly state :

> Run all tests serially in the current process, rather than creating a worker pool of child processes that run tests. This can be useful for debugging.

And Yes it would be useful for debugging but why am I getting a child process still ? I did try --workerThreads , it's experimental but IDK maybe it could work, but no, still can't see any real memory usage in the debugger.

What I am missing ? I also tried

```bash
NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect-brk' node --expose-gc ./node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand --logHeapUsage
```

In the hope that the child process would attach itself to the debugger but no luck.

Does someone has any idea ?